# Creating SVN project from new and existing SVN files

Tags: tortoisesvn

My new Tortoise SVN repository project should be mix of some files on my local disk and some files already part of another existing project in SVN. Regarding those (existing) files, can I simply copy them using repo browser into new project and then do check out to bring them into local working copy ? Or should I check out existing files to working folder of new project, then add new local files to it and after that add all of them to mentioned new repo project ? Or ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions depending on your application:

- **if you do not want to duplicate the existing files** in the repository: you should use `svn:externals` property (see [Subversion doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) and [TortoiseSVN doc](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html)). This allows you retrieving in the working copy of your new project some folders coming from another location in repository (e.g. from another project). The constraint is that you can do that with entire folders, not separate files.
- **if you don't matter duplicating the file**s in the repository: in your local working copy (not in the repo browser), you should select the files you want to copy, right click and choose *Context Menu → Copy* from the explorer context menu. Then browse to the target folder, right click and choose *TortoiseSVN → Paste*. Then commit all in once. This is described [here](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html).